# How to count elements in array field in a mongoose query

Tags: mongoose, count

I have a query like this:

```
const posts = await Post.find(req.body)
```

and its returns a colection of post documents like this:

```
    post: {
     _id: "mongoIdcode",
     content: "Some string content",
     likes : [usermongooseid1, usermoongoseid2, usermoongoseid3, ...],
     dislikes : [usermongooseid1, usermoongoseid2, usermoongoseid3, ...]
    }
```

How can I get the count of likes and dislikes fields using mongoose?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Gilson401 what is your condition to find query?

Comment: Hi  @SagarPednekar. The condition may change. It's not fixed. But at first you can consider req.body as {} (empty) and thus returns without any filter.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution , needed to use .aggregate method of mongoose.